# Import ~/.ssh/config into Putty

Tags: windows, ssh, putty

I have a large amount of servers configured in my ~/.ssh/config on my Linux workstation. Currently I am however using a Windows workstation most of the time, and I'm wondering if it's possible to import the config into Putty to avoid having to add the servers by hand?

Best regards,

David

Comment: Might be easier to accomplish with KiTTY, because it can store its configuration in files (instead of the registry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must also apologize, I hate when people answer "Don't do what you asked, use this other software instead". Hope you don't mind.
https://cygwin.com/install.html

If you're familiar with ssh on linux, I might recommend not migrating to PuTTy.

I have fully abandoned PuTTy on my windows workstation and instead live in cygwin + tmux + openssh.

Just copy your .ssh/config to your home directory in Cygwin and you'll be good to go.

My suggestion does assume that you have permissions to run the cygwin-setup.exe

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use the openssh port to PowerShell/Windows.
 https://chocolatey.org/packages/openssh

I have been using this for a few months now and haven't hone back to cygwin or WSL shells for SSH.  It fully supports the client side config file in the location you expect - $HOME/.ssh, no need to keep track of which $HOME your settings are under.

If you are lucky enough to use the Creator edition of Windows 10 the openssh port is complete and is now a native PowerShell cmdlet.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/12/15/using-the-openssh-beta-in-windows-10-fall-creators-update-and-windows-server-1709/